# Add pins to Google Map in a TWebBrowser and process clicks

Tags: android, ios, delphi, google-maps, delphi-xe5

How do I add pins to a Google Map in a TWebBrowser and call an event when a pin is clicked? The solution needs to work on both iOS and Android.

Comment: This any good? http://www.jasontpenny.com/blog/2008/10/29/interact-with-google-maps-in-a-twebbrowser-from-delphi/

Comment: @jasonflaherty - iOS/Android, not Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make some bridging between native (iOS/Android) and your GoogleMaps javascript code. To drop a pin on the map for example, you will have to inject js code calling your addPin method on js side.

On iOS, it's done by calling a web view method called stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:

```
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"addPin()"];
```

and to listen to tap events on webview, you will have to implement a callback when the pin is tapped, and call your objC method using the iFrame approach:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
iframe.setAttribute("src", "js-frame:myPinTappedMethod";
document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
iframe = null;
```

It will trigger web view's shouldStartLoadWithRequest: delegate on native side, so all you have to do is read the request and process ...

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{

  // Intercept custom location change, URL begins with "js-call:"
  if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"js-call:"]) {

    // Extract the selector name from the URL
    NSArray *components = [requestString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    NSString * functionName = [components objectAtIndex:1];

    // Call the given selector
    [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(functionName)];

    // Cancel the location change
    return NO;
  }

  // Accept this location change
  return YES;

}
```

Part of this example I take from [here](http://blog.techno-barje.fr//post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/)

Hope it helps!